# An inline collapsible whose ending X coordinate depends in its starting X coordinate

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to implement special styles/scripts for collapsibles on my webpage.

Let's assume the following original HTML:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
> adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
> incididunt ut labore et **<div class="my-collapsible">Hello world!</div>** dolore magna
> aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
> nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
> nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

In the collapsed form it should look very simplistically, just a single inline dingbat, e.g. “⊞” (N.B.: I'm adding scrollbars at the right just to depict the width of the browser window, it's not a part of the planned design):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ▲
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor  ░
incididunt ut labore et ⊞ dolore magna  ░
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis   ░
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris    ░
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.▼
```

But in expanded form it should look like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ▲
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor  ░
incididunt ut labore et ┌─────────────┐ ░
┌───────────────────────┘             │ ░
│                                     │ ░
│            Hello, world!            │ ░
│                                     │ ░
│                        ┌────────────┘ ░
└────────────────────────┘ dolore magna ░
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis   ░
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris    ░
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.▼
```

I.e. from some point of view it can be said that it consists of three parts: top (inline?) part **till the end of the line**; main (block?) part with the “Hello, world!”; bottom (inline?) part, which starts at the beginning of the line and **ends approximately at the same X coordinate where the top part starts**. So, the text which follows the collapsible must start approximately at the same X coordinate where the text preceding the collapsible ends. And, of course, it should work independently of the page width, text available of the page, font and etc. Illustration (depicting the top and the bottom parts with another shading and marking the maintained X coordinate with a virtual line):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ▲
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor  ░
incididunt ut labore et ███████████████ ░
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒│▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ░
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒│▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ░
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒Hello, world!▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ░
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒│▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ░
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒│▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ░
█████████████████████████ dolore magna  ░
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis   ░
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris    ░
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.▼
```

(I am asking only about the expanded state. Of course, the collapsed state doesn't make a problem, neither switching between collapsed and expanded states does.)

I understand, that it's probably impossible to implement that with pure CSS.

The only implementation that I can imagine is putting additional elements before and after the collapsible and changing their size in `onresize`-like event, like this one:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.my-collapsible').forEach(collapsible => {
  let pre = collapsible.previousElementSibling;
  //console.assert(pre.classList.contains('my-collapsible-pre'));
  let post = collapsible.nextElementSibling;
  //console.assert(post.classList.contains('my-collapsible-post'));
  new ResizeObserver(() => {
    let x = pre.offsetLeft - collapsible.offsetLeft;
    pre.firstChild.style.width = (collapsible.offsetWidth - x) + 'px';
    post.style.width = (x + pre.offsetWidth) + 'px';
  }).observe(collapsible.parentElement);
});
```

```css
.my-collapsible,
.my-collapsible-pre>div,
.my-collapsible-post {
  background-color: silver;
  border: solid gray 1px;
}

.my-collapsible-pre,
.my-collapsible-post {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 1em;
}

.my-collapsible-pre {
  overflow: visible;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  width: 1em/* -- indentionally made a bit more than 0 */
}

.my-collapsible-pre>div {
  border-bottom: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

.my-collapsible-post {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: none;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.my-collapsible {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
<div class="my-collapsible-pre"><div></div></div><div class="my-collapsible">
  Hello, world!
</div><div class="my-collapsible-post"></div> dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

Are there any ways to simplify this solution?

Comment: It happened that I've wrote a working solution while composing the question. I am not expert in this area and am not sure that this solution is the best one, but with the answer inside the question may look like “WTH he wants from us?!!” Should I: (0) leave it as is, (1) turn the “like this one” of the question part into a self-answer, (2) move the question to the https://codereview.stackexchange.com or (3) just delete it?

Comment: Hi @Sasha if you want to know how you can improve your solution then you can post on Code Review. If you are not interested in how to improve upon your solution then posting there would be inappropriate. If this sounds like something you'd like then check [if it is on-topic](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to post a good question](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You will likely need to change a lot of the wording for your question to be a match there.